# How to put html inside event handlers

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

```
 <s:Button click="showMessage('<h1>Some message</h1>')" label="Как играть?" />
```

How to put an html message, in the handler, because I get an error of the parser that says, that inside click handlers there not be `<` symbols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also call your function in this way.

```
<s:Button label="Как играть?" >
        <s:click >
            <![CDATA[
                showMessage('<h1>Some message</h1>');
            ]]>
        </s:click>
    </s:Button>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the MXML-syntax, work standard methods of escaping special chars:

1. [prefixing it with the backslash character `\`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/mxmlSyntax_3.html#188499)
2. [using "HTML Number" code](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/mxmlSyntax_3.html#185108) or also "ASCII Dec" (see [table](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm))
3. [Wrap your text in a CDATA tag](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/textcontrols_04.html#437422).

e.g.:

```
<ns:myComp...>
    <ns:click>
        <![CDATA[
            // your AS3 code
        ]]>
    </ns:click>
    <ns:htmlText>
        <![CDATA[
            This is 14 point blue italic text.<br/>
            <b><font color="#000000" size="10">text</font></b>
        ]]>
    </ns:htmlText>
    ...
```

And I **recommend** you write a separate listener in `<fx:Script>` tag.

Comment: Based on the code in the question; I would say that the poster does have a separate listener in `<fx:Script>' named `showMessage()`.  I don't think that `<' and `>' can be escaped with the '\' character.

Answer (score 3):

Escape them:

```
 <s:Button click="showMessage('&lt;h1&gt;Some message&lt;/h1&gtl')" label="Как играть?" />
```

That should get rid of compiler errors.  Without knowing what the showMessage button does; it is tough to tell whether this will give you the desired results or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to do something like this.

It would be easier to change the handler to accept more properties:

```
protected function showMessage(heading:String, message:String):void {
     var message:String = '<h1>' + heading + '</h1><p>' + message + '</p>';
     // do something with message.
}
<s:Button click="showMessage('Title', 'Custom message.')" label="Click Me"/>
```